# What is file format or extension of android things App?

Tags: android, android-things, android-things-console

As we know that the extension of Android app is .APK. likewise, I want to know the app extension of android things app.

Comment: Why should be a different extension? Android is Android.

Answer (score 2):

The extension for Android Things app is also `.apk`.

See [Create a build for an Android Things product](https://developer.android.com/things/console/build)

> ...applications are compiled and packaged into a single file with the .apk extension (an Android application package file)